# Importing an animated Blender tree into Unity

Tags: unity, animation, blender

I've been trying to import a tree blowing in the wind (using Blender's `Sapling Tree Gen`) into Unity to play the animation. However, I can't get it to play

The steps I took are as follows:

1. Created a tree in blender. Selected `Show Leaves` under "Leaves", `Use Armature` under "Armature", and `Armature Animation` and `Leaf Animation` under "Animation".
2. Selected all components under `treeArm` in the scene collection, and exported as FBX:
   [image: Export settings]
3. Imported into unity. Here, when I double-click the animation (moving triangle) and try to play it in the inspector, the branches don't move, and the leaves are completely absent.

[image]

I also tried following [these instructions](https://base.xsens.com/s/article/FBX-import-into-Unity?language=en_US#ImportAnimationFBX_2.2) but that didn't do anything either.

I'm trying to get the tree-moving-in-the-wind animation to play on a loop

...How do I do it?

Edit: It seems [someone has figured it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264462/unity-animation-is-too-fast-when-exporting-from-blender) but didn't share how...

Edit 2: I forgot to mention that in the animation window in Unity, there's definitely... something. It seems to me that the data for the animation is properly imported (though everything seems to be about rotation, and there's nothing to do with position)

[image]

[Link to the .blend file](https://github.com/ReallyCoolName/Blender2Unity_Tree/blob/main/tree_in_wind.blend)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? If not, send a link to your blender project so I can detail the answer and even test the best way.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso I haven't figured it out yet. Thank you for offering to help. I found an alternative solution, but I am curious how to get this one to work anyway. So if you're as curious as I am about this, I've edited the question and added the following link:
https://github.com/ReallyCoolName/Blender2Unity_Tree/blob/main/tree_in_wind.blend

Comment: I don't know if got the solution for this! but i have one...this work for me.
watch this video: https://youtu.be/onn-WAKwKsg?si=T2M5w7PX5qjIl4c0 and for import settings use what you are using previously...